# How to add a required attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html, required

I have a script that shows some and hides some html but I dont know how to add the required tag when it is shown, I have already tried to add the attribute in the section that I want it but it requires it even when not shown... can someone help me out. thanks in advance!

```
<div  class="start"><select name="start" class="form-control">
           <option value="0" class="select">Select City</option>
                <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
                    <option <? echo 'value="'.$row['id'].'"';
                        echo ($row['id'] == $job['start'])?' selected>':'>'; 
                        echo $row['name']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select></div><br />
            <br />
            <script>
            $('select[name=start]').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '89') {
                    $('#otherStart').show();
                } else {
                    $('#otherStart').hide();
                }
            });
            </script>
            <br />
            <div id="otherStart">
                <input type="text" name="otherStart" placeholder="Other City" <? echo ($job['otherStart'])?' value="'.$job['otherStart'].'"':''; 
            ?> class="form-control" >
            </div>
```

Comment: The `required` attribute? Add it to what element and when? `$('#otherStart').show().attr("required", "required");`. You should tag your question with `jquery` btw, since you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to assign an `id`-attribute to the input you're modifying, so that we can change the attributes with jQuery. You already use `<div id="otherStart">` to show/hide the entire div, so select another name, for example `id="inputOtherStart"` (IDs should always be unique).

Then we use jQuery to add and remove the attribute when we show and hide the `div`, respectively.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // Function to show/hide the extra subject-field, and making it required or not
    var Start = '#Start';
    var otherStart = '#otherStart';
    var otherStartInput = '#otherStartInput';

    $(otherStart).hide(); 
    $(Start).change(function(){
        if($(Start).val() == 89) {
            $(otherStart).show();
            $(otherStartInput).prop('required',true);
        } else {
            $(otherStart).hide(); 
            $(otherStartInput).prop('required',false);
        } 
    });
});
</script>
<br />
<div id="otherStart">
    <input type="text" id="otherStartInput" name="otherStart" placeholder="Other City" <? echo ($job['otherStart'])?' value="'.$job['otherStart'].'"':''; ?> class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried doing it this way and it makes sense but for some reason it does not add the attribute

Comment: Did you add the `id`-attribute to the `input`? And how did you check that it doesn't add the attribute (inspecting code wouldn't work).

Comment: @MrJohnDowe Try it now, I've updated the jQuery-script. Tested it as well, this one should work, provided the `input` has the appropriate `id`.

Comment: I cant test it properly because now the otherStart wont show when Other is selected

Comment: Wasn't that the purpose though? You could just comment out the lines dealing with `hide()` and `show()` while testing, if needed. I have tested it though, and this code works as intended.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery libary? Inside your HTML `<head>`-tag, add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: if figured the last part out instead of var Start = '#Start';
it should have been var start = 'select[name=start]';

Comment: Happy to have helped :) If you found this answer helpful, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a certain element required in jQuery you should use `.prop`:

```
$(selector).prop("required", true);
```

You could also do it in JavaScript using the attribute `required`:

```
element.required = true;
```

Or again,

```
element.setAttribute("required","");
```

Answer (score 0):

To add and remove attribute "required" when div shows and hides you can modify your JavaScript as-

```
          <script>
            $('select[name=start]').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '89') {
                    $('#otherStart').show();
                    $('#otherStart : input').attr('required');
                } else {
                    $('#otherStart').hide();
                    $('#otherStart : input').removeAttr('required');
                }
            });
            </script>
```